# Object within object data structure in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm receiving these results from an API:

```
{
  "97": {
    "Title": "This is a title",
  },
  "98": {
    "Title": "This is another title",
  }
}
```

I'm using this interface:

```
export interface Product {
  Title: string;
}

export interface SKU {
  [key: string]: Product
}
```

Does my interface looks alright? And how do I work with this type of stracture in Angular regarding *ngFor?

Comment: It looks okay to me. To use with `ngFor` you would have to convert this to an array or something you can iterate over

Comment: There's also the [keyvalue](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe depending on what version you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks okay  I think , 
and  for  using  this  with  ngFor  I think  you need to convert  the object to array  using map  function  .

```
    var arr = Object.keys(objectName).map((index)=>{
    let item = objectName[index];

    return item ;
});
```

and then using  arr  within  *ngFor

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is an array

```
[
    "97": {
        "Title": "This is a title",
     },
    "98": {
        "Title": "This is another title",
     }
]
```

to parse your API response as `SKU[]`. To achieve this structure you can either correct your server code (correct way to do it) or do some fancy object to array conversions (don‘t do).

After parsing this result in your component as `SKU[]` you can iterate in your view using `*ngFor`.